# Why don't my ValidateEntity errors show up in my view?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I've got some POCO Model classes that I've setup for use with the Entity Framework. I do some validation in my `DbContext`'s `ValidateEntity` override. I return a `DbEntityValidationResult` from the `ValidateEntity` function, and I can see that during run-time I do add some `DbValidationError`s. I can even see those errors inside of the `ModelState` inside of my `Controller` function, using the following code ...

```
catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
{
    foreach (var entity in ex.EntityValidationErrors)
    {
        foreach (var error in entity.ValidationErrors)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(error.PropertyName, error.ErrorMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

But for some reason those errors don't show up for the desired property name in the Razor view. I use a view model that looks like the following ...

```
public class CharacterCreateModel
{
    private Character m_character;

    #region Properties

    public Character Character
    {
        get
        {
            return m_character;
        }

        set
        {
            m_character = value;
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

And in my Razor view, which is strongly typed using this `CharacterCreateModel` view mode, I just use the standard `@Html.TextBoxFor`, etc.

Validation errors coming from the `Character` model properly display, but validation errors from the `ValidateEntity` function are not showing up for that property name.

Any idea why not?

Comment: Post your view 
page !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the ValidationMessageFor helper in your code to show model level properties.

You should have

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Character)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Character)
```

If this in not showing the errors change the

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
```

at the top of your view to

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(false)
```

so you can see all the validation errors and make sure they're actually being added correctly.